# Fetching data from JSON in Angular2 not working

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to fetch data from a JSON File that I have in my assets folder in Angular 2, but it's not showing it. I want to get the data from the following JSON file:

test.json

```
[
    "{'id': 1, 'building': 'Edificio 4', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 1, 'school': 1}",
    "{'id': 2, 'building': 'Edificio 15', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 0, 'school': 1}",
    "{'id': 3, 'building': 'Edificio 15', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 1, 'school': 1}",
    "{'id': 4, 'building': 'Edificio 2', 'zone': 'C', 'floor': 2, 'school': 2}",
    "{'id': 5, 'building': 'Edificio 2', 'zone': 'B', 'floor': 3, 'school': 2}",
    "{'id': 6, 'building': 'Edificio 7', 'zone': 'J', 'floor': 7, 'school': 2}"
]
```

The component where I'm trying to do it is this one:

locker.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

//this is the data class
class Place{
  constructor(public id: string, public building: string, public zone: string, public floor: string, public school: string) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-locker',
  template: `
  //here i have a template
`,
  styleUrls: ['./locker.component.css'],

})

@Injectable()
export class LockerComponent implements OnInit {

  places: Place[];
//if I manually add the data by hand here it works,
//I want to fetch the JSON data to this array

  campus: String;
  building: String;
  floor: String;
  zone: String;
  type: String;

  buildings = [];
  floors = [];
  zones = [];
  types = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('./assets/test.json').subscribe(data => {
    this.places = data;
    });
  }
}
```

I also have imported HttpClientModule in my app.component.ts as stated in https://angular.io/guide/http

I've read other stackoverflow answers to similar questions, but they don't seem to work, and answers are kind of blurry because they don't show all the code but only snippets.

Any ideas on why this is not working?

I also put here the function I'm using to show the data on one of the selects based on what I chose in the other:

```
onChangeCampus(event: any){
    const campus = event.target.value;
    this.buildings.length = 0;
    this.floors.length = 0;
    this.zones.length = 0;
    this.types.length = 0;
    for(let i of this.places){
      if (i.school == campus && !(this.buildings.indexOf(i.building) > -1)){
        this.buildings.push(i.building);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have to import HttpClient

Comment: please share actualc `json` file  so that we can help you

Comment: floor , school , id are int in json but you declare string in class Place

Comment: @Kyrsberg Importing HttpClient stops the error but the data is still not fetched, I'm using it for a dynamic form and it shows like an empty array.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Editing right now

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh if I declare something as int in the ts file, it says "angular cannot find name int"

Comment: @CarlosManuelHernández declare it as number

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh done, but still says that type "Object" is not assignable to type Place[]

Comment: I have edited the question to explain the problem.

Comment: You can type the return value as Place type. this.http.get('./assets/test.json').subscribe((data: Place)=> {
    this.places = data;
    });

Comment: @Kyrsberg thanks! Now it shows no compilation error but it still not fetching the data :(

Comment: @CarlosManuelHernández only for debugging put `[{
  "id": 1,
  "building": "Edificio 1",
  "zone": "Sin zonas ",
  "floor": 1,
  "school": 1
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "building": "Edificio 2",
  "zone": "Sin zonas",
  "floor": 2,
  "school": 2
 }
]` in your json file

Comment: Have you checked your browsers developer tools? You should be able to see a request in networking tab. You could also console.log the data

Comment: It says 304 not modified @Kyrsberg , but looks like the request was done correctly. I added the function I'm using to show the data in one select based on what I chose on the first.

Comment: Doing console.log this.places returned this:  Array [ "{'id': 1, 'building': 'Edificio 4', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 1, 'school': 1}", "{'id': 2, 'building': 'Edificio 15', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 0, 'school': 1}", "{'id': 3, 'building': 'Edificio 15', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 1, 'school': 1}", "{'id': 4, 'building': 'Edificio 2', 'zone': 'C', 'floor': 2, 'school': 2}", "{'id': 5, 'building': 'Edificio 2', 'zone': 'B', 'floor': 3, 'school': 2}", "{'id': 6, 'building': 'Edificio 7', 'zone': 'J', 'floor': 7, 'school': 2}" ]

Comment: @CarlosManuelHernández your json array every index return as string like this `"{'id': 1, 'building': 'Edificio 4', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 1, 'school': 1}"`

Comment: Can I actually "parse" it to match my class Place? @ManinderpreetSingh

Comment: @CarlosManuelHernández ...Kyrsberg answerd it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like Lucas aswered your first problem was with return value type

```
this.http.get<Place[]>('./assets/test.json').subscribe(data => {
   this.places = data;
 });
```

I believe you test.json format is little off too.

```
[
    "{'id': 1, 'building': 'Edificio 4', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 1, 'school': 1}",
    "{'id': 2, 'building': 'Edificio 15', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 0, 'school': 1}",
    "{'id': 3, 'building': 'Edificio 15', 'zone': 'Sin zonas', 'floor': 1, 'school': 1}",
    "{'id': 4, 'building': 'Edificio 2', 'zone': 'C', 'floor': 2, 'school': 2}",
    "{'id': 5, 'building': 'Edificio 2', 'zone': 'B', 'floor': 3, 'school': 2}",
    "{'id': 6, 'building': 'Edificio 7', 'zone': 'J', 'floor': 7, 'school': 2}"
]
```

When it should be something like this. I removed the wrapping " marks and changed ' to " marks

```
[
  {"id": 1, "building": "Edificio4", "zone": "Sin zonas", "floor": 1, "school": 1},
  {"id": 2, "building": "Edificio15", "zone": "Sin zonas", "floor": 0, "school": 1},
  {"id": 3, "building": "Edificio15", "zone": "Sin zonas", "floor": 1, "school": 1},
  {"id": 4, "building": "Edificio2", "zone": "C", "floor": 2, "school": 2},
  {"id": 5, "building": "Edificio2", "zone": "B", "floor": 3, "school": 2},
  {"id": 6, "building": "Edificio7", "zone": "J", "floor": 7, "school": 2}
]
```

Comment: One last question. In the end, I'm going to get the data from an API (the JSON is exactly the same, but instead of being in local storage, it is in an api). Will this work just by changing the url from './assets/test.json' to the URL of the REST API? @Kyrsberg

Answer (score 2):

You should define the return value of the request:

```
 this.http.get<Place[]>('./assets/test.json').subscribe(data => {
   this.places = data;
 });
```

Comment: As in @Kyrsberg answer, this works as it doesn't show any compilation errors, but it is still not fetching the data I believe, because the form doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the json file through httpClient module by calling to :

```
getFile():Observable<Object>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/file.json');
}
```

and you have to keep the file in the assets folder so that you can access it .
i hope that will help.